# How to display information for a specific item from a database through a for loop?

Tags: python, jquery, html, web2py

I'm using the web2py frame work and this is what i'm trying to achieve;
I have contact details of different places in my DB, the names of these different places are displayed as links in a page, ***what i want is for the contact details of a place to be displayed in a tooltip when i click on the link name of that place.*** But that is not happening! What happens is that when i click the name of the place i get tooltips with different contact information of different places stacked on top of each other!

As stated above, ***what i want is for the contact details of a place to be displayed in a tooltip when i click on the link name of that place.***, can anyone please assist me get this right.

**THE MODEL CODE**

```
db.define_table('services',
            Field('service_name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
           format='%(service_name)s', migrate=False, fake_migrate=True)

db.define_table('company',
            Field('logo', 'upload'),
            Field('company_name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('services', 'reference services'),
            #Field('tlamelo', 'reference tlamelo'),
            Field('product', 'reference product'),
            Field('tel', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('email', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('fax', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('cell', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('facebook', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('twitter', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('website', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('postal_address', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('located_at', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()), migrate=False, fake_migrate=True)
```

**CSS TOOLTIP CODE**

```
#branch1 {outline:none; position: relative; font-weight: bold;}
#branch1 {text-decoration:none;}
span.contacts1
{ 
    display:inline; 
    position:absolute; 
    color:#111; 
    border:1px solid #000000;
    background: #000000; 
    opacity: 0.9; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: small; 
    border:1px solid #000000; 
    border-radius: 25px;/*border-radius: 5px 100px 5px;*/
    z-index:1; 
    left: 40px; 
    display:none; 
    padding:14px 15px; 
    margin-top:-56px; 
    margin-left:70px; 
    width:500px; 
    line-height:16px;line-height:20px;
}
```

**CONTROLLER CODE**

```
def companies():
    results=db.services(request.args(0))
    rslts=db(db.company.services==results.id).select(db.company.ALL, orderby=db.company.company_name)
    return locals()
```

**THE VIEW CODE**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.branch1').click(function(e) {
            $(this).each(function(){
                $('.contacts1').fadeIn();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        });
         $('img#close').click(function(e)
         {
             $('.contacts1').fadeOut();
             e.preventDefault();
         });
        });
    </script>


<div class="comps">
<span class="companies">COMPANIES (A-F)</span><br /><br />
{{letters=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
for company in rslts:
    if company.company_name[0] in letters:
company.company_name
}}

<a href="#" id="branch1" class="branch1 branches">{{=company.company_name}}</a><br />
<span class="contacts1">
<a href="#"><img src="{{=URL('static', 'images/close.png')}}" style="width: 50px; position: absolute; top:0px;right:0px;" id="close"/></a>
<div class="info" id="logo">
   <img id="companyLogo" width="140px" src="{{=URL('download',args=company.logo)}}" /><br />
   <span style="position: absolute; bottom:0px; left: 10px;">SESOA&trade</span>
</div>


<div class="info" style="padding-left:5px; border-left: solid 1px white;" id="details">
    <span class="companyName">{{=company.company_name}}</span>
    <hr class="divider" />
    <span class="contact" id="cell">TEL: </spanM <strongstyle="color:green;">{{=company.tel}}</strong><br />
<span class="contact" id="cell">EM@IL: </span> <strong style="color:green;">{{=company.email}}</strong><br />
<span class="contact" id="cell">CELL: </span><strong style="color:green;">{{=company.cell}}</strong><br />
<span class="contact" id="fb">Facebook: </span>  <strong style="color:green;">{{=company.facebook}}</strong><br />

<span class="contact" id="twit">Twitter: </span> <strong style="color:green;">{{=company.twitter}}</strong><br />
    <a href="{{=company.website}}" target="_blank"><span class="contact" id="e_mail">WEBSITE: </span> <strong style="color:green;">{{=company.website}}</strong></span></a><br />

<span class="contact" id="cell">FAX: </span> <strong style="color:green;">{{=company.fax}}</strong><br />
<span class="contact" id="cell">LOCATION: </span> <strong style="color:green;">{{=company.located_at}}</strong><br />
</div>
</span>

         {{pass}}
        {{pass}}
</div>
```

Click this link to view the problem first hand [Contacts Problem Example](https://contacts.pythonanywhere.com/init/default/companies2/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the click handler, contacts are shown via:

```
$('.contacts1').fadeIn()
```

However, in the `for` loop, each contact gets a "contacts1" class, so the above selector selects all the contacts to be faded in whenever any link is clicked.

Instead, you must add a unique identifier to each contact and select only that contact when its link is clicked.

Try changing:

```
<a href="#" id="branch1" class="branch1 branches">{{=company.company_name}}</a><br />
<span class="contacts1">
```

to:

```
<a href="#" class="branch1 branches" data-id="{{=company.id}}">{{=company.company_name}}</a><br />
<span class="contacts1" id="{{=company.id}}">
```

Notice that the company id is added as the unique `id` for the contacts element, and that same id is added as the `data-id` attribute of the associated link.

Then, set up the click handler like this:

```
    $('.branch1').click(function(e) {
        const id = $(this).data('id'); // Extract the data-id attribute of the link.
        $('#' + id).fadeIn(); // Select the contact with that id.
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Also, note that in an HTML page, each `id` attribute must be unique, but you re-use the same `id` values in each loop (i.e., "branch1", "close", "logo"). You even re-use the "cell" `id` multiple times within a single iteration of the loop. It is not clear you even need all of those `id`'s, but if you do need any of them, make sure they are unique (e.g., something like `"{{='branch%s' % company.id}}"`).